Hamiltonian Group Actions on Calabi-Yau Cones
Let $(M, g, J, \omega, \Omega)$ be a Calabi-Yau cone (where $\Omega \in \Gamma(K_M)$ is the parallel holomorphic volume form), and assume we have a Hamiltonian group action $G \circlearrowright M$ preserving the Calabi-Yau structure, with moment map $\mu: M \to \mathfrak{g}^*$. Assume that the action preserves the radial coordinate of the cone, i.e. it is an action on the Sasaki-Einstein link.
e.g. In the case $M = \mathbb{C}^n$, $G \leq SU(n)$, the group preserves the Calabi-Yau structure and acts on the link $S^{2n-1}$. A suitable moment map is $\langle \mu(z), X \rangle = \frac{i}{2} \overline z^T X z$ for $X \in \mathfrak{g}$.
My question is: when are the level sets of $\mu$ themselves conical? For example, in the $\mathbb{C}^n$ case, the zero level set $\mu^{-1}(0)$ can be seen to be a cone by the explicit form given above. Is a $\mu^{-1}(0)$ a cone in the general Calabi-Yau cone setting, or are there counterexamples?

I will only keep the part of the structure which is relevant: the symplectic form $\omega$, the action of the group $G$ and the "cone" structure, which is (for there purposes) a vector field $E$ on $M$ preserved by the action of $G$ and satisfying $L_E\omega = \omega$. If we set $\theta =i_E\omega$ then $d\theta=\omega$ and $\theta$ is preserved by the action of $G$, so we get a moment map $\mu$ for the $G$-action by $\langle v,\mu\rangle = i_{\rho(v)}\theta$ ($v\in\mathfrak g$, $\rho$ is the action). Since $L_E\theta=\theta$ and $L_E\rho(v)=0$, we get $E\mu=\mu$. As a consequence, $E$ is tangent to $\mu^{-1}(0)$.
There is now only one minor problem: your moment map might not be equal to the $\mu$ which I described; they might differ by a $G$-invariant element of $\mathfrak g^*$. But for many $G$'s such an element just has to be $0$ (the $G$-invariance means that it is a Lie algebra homomorphism $\mathfrak g\to\mathbb R$).

Thanks, this is extremely helpful!
